# Request multiple REST API at the same time

Tags: android, rx-android

My purpose is request double REST API in the same time with Retrofit and their responses are List. I want to handle each response to update to View (response 1 is OK -> View1 show data, response2 is error -> View2 show error). How can I do this with RxAndroid?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to build retrofit with RxAdapter as retrofit adapter factory, then each request should return Observable

To register RXAdapter to retrofit

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
```

After that in retrofit's ApiInterface should return observable, for instance, say you want to get list of users and list of courses

```
@GET("users")
Observable<List<User>> getUsers();
@GET("courses")
Observable<List<Course>> getCourses();
```

After that in presenter or wherever you handle your logic you need to subscribe

```
getUsers()
  .zipWith(getCourses(),Pair::new)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread)
  .subscribe(usersAndCoursesPair -> {
     //update your view
   },throwable -> //print any error could occur
  }
```

Comment: I'm appreciate a lot for your completely answer, by the way I want to show listUser by recyclerView in fragmentA and listCourse in fragmentB. I needn't to pair or combine the response.

Comment: so no need zip the responses then, just remove zipWith operator and it'll return users list to be displayed in fragA and do the same with courses

Comment: So I can't use RxJava in this case? Because I want View wait for 2 requests be done and update data had received.

Comment: can you tell me your use case to help you more, are those two fragments are displayed at the same time ?

Comment: Yep, My flight is return flight, so I need to get 2 List<Flight>. I show in 2 fragment at the same time; these fragments are inside a viewPager adapter.

Comment: well, you can do it by zipping both requests in the activity and whenever both items are loaded update your fragments by sending event bus or broadcast with the loaded item.

Answer (score 0):

you can call this multiple time as it is an async Callback using Square's Retrofit

```
public void Prepare_Review_data() {
    try {
        if (token != null) {
            if (isConnected()) try {
                loading = ProgressHUD.show(getContext(), "Loading Reviews", true, false, Heizolscout_Reviews.this);
                Call<JsonElement> call = apiService.Heizolscout_Reviews("Bearer " + token.getAccessToken());
                call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                        Log.d("History Information", response.toString());
                        loading.dismiss();
                        if (response.code() == 401) {
                            Fragment frag = new Heizolscout_Login();
                            if (frag != null) {
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                ft.replace(R.id.sacreenarea, frag);
                                ft.commit();
                            }
                        } else if (response.code() == 200) {
                            try {
                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Review_Model>>(){}.getType();
                                ArrayList<Review_Model>noti = gson.fromJson(response.body(), listType);
                                Log.d("Notification success",Review_models.size()+"");
                                if (noti.size()>0){
                                    for (Review_Model n:noti){
                                        Review_models.add(n);
                                    }
                                    Review_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.review_no_list_string), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                Review_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("Error Line Number", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                            }
                            try {
                                Log.d("History error", response.body().getAsJsonObject().get("error").toString());
                                if (!response.body().getAsJsonObject().get("error").isJsonNull()) {
                                    Show_Alert(getString(R.string.open_email), response.body().getAsJsonObject().get("error").toString(), getString(R.string.ok), getString(R.string.normal));
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("Error Line Number", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                            }
                        } else if (response.code() == 422) {
                            Show_Alert(getString(R.string.invalid_tittle), getString(R.string.invalid_tittle_details), getString(R.string.ok), getString(R.string.normal));
                        } else {
                            Show_Alert(getString(R.string.error_tittle), getString(R.string.error_tittle_details), getString(R.string.ok), getString(R.string.normal));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                        // Log error here since request failed
                        Log.e("Error", t.toString());
                        Show_Alert(getString(R.string.error_tittle), getString(R.string.error_tittle_details), getString(R.string.ok), getString(R.string.normal));
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                loading.dismiss();
                Log.d("Error Line Number", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
            else {
                Show_Alert(getString(R.string.internet_tittle), getString(R.string.internet_details), getString(R.string.ok), getString(R.string.nointernet));
            }
        } else {
            Fragment frag = new Heizolscout_Login();
            if (frag != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.sacreenarea, frag);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error Line Number", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guy. Your way is really good, I try my best to learn from you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using `Observable.zip()`

In your case would be something like this:

`Observable.zip( request1, request2.doOnError(//show error here), 
BiFunction<response1,response2, combinedResponses>{response1, response2 
-> new CombinedResponses(response1, response2)}).subscribe(new Observer{...})`

If you need more info you can always look into the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

Comment: Thanks for your support. It look like answer I need, I'm trying now. I will be back with another question cause I don't really understand a lot about RxJava now.